# Get item and subitem

Tags: javascript

I need help.

I have this very simple html: https://jsfiddle.net/z8y7Lv2a/

```
<header>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Sobre</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">O que fazemos</a>
    </li>
    <li data-submenu='Nossas sedes'>
      <a href="#">Nossas sedes</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Curitiba</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Acre</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Salvador</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-submenu='Serviços'>
      <a href="#">Serviços</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Google Analytics</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Google Tag Manager</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

I'm trying to give console when a link is clicked following this rule:

If it is a main link, only the name of the link will appear, for example, clicking on 'About' the console will display 'About'.

By clicking on a submenu, the console should display the parent's name + the title clicked on, for example: Nossas sedes-Curitiba

Can you help me?

If it is a main link, only the name of the link will appear, for example, clicking on 'About' the console will display 'About'.

By clicking on a submenu, the console should display the parent's name + the title clicked on, for example: Nossas sedes-Curitiba

Comment: Can you post your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not perfectly sure because in your question you talked about the menu item `About` when describing the behaviour of the click on a link not having a parent item.. but it isn't included in the html you shared.

By the way here's a demo that attempts to achieve what you where asking..

On document ready it adds a click event handler on all anchor elements being inside an header element.

Such event handler will fetch the element being clicked by doing `event.target` and attempts to fetch the closest li parent having the data attribute `data-submenu`. If it exists and it's different compared to the immediate parent node, it logs on console the composition of such data attribute value and the clicked element inner text. Otherwise it will just print out the clicked element inner text.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('header a')
  .forEach(anchor => {
    anchor.addEventListener('click', event => {
      const clickedElement = event.target;    
      const parentSubmenu = clickedElement.closest('li[data-submenu]');      
      if(parentSubmenu && parentSubmenu !== clickedElement.parentNode ){
        console.log(`${parentSubmenu.dataset.submenu}-${clickedElement.innerText}`);
      }else{
        console.log(clickedElement.innerText);
      }      
    });
  });
```

```html
<header>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Sobre</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">O que fazemos</a>
    </li>
    <li data-submenu='Nossas sedes'>
      <a href="#">Nossas sedes</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Curitiba</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Acre</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Salvador</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-submenu='Serviços'>
      <a href="#">Serviços</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Google Analytics</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Google Tag Manager</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: as a side note.. I didn't specify that to make it work as is, the safest way would be to wrap it inside a DOMContentLoaded event handler .. just because you'll be sure that the dom will be there when trying to fetch the header node to attach the click event handlers to its anchor childrens

Answer (score -1):

In your header, you want to add an element where the title will be displayed:

```html
<header>
  <h1 id="title">
  </h1>
  <ul>
   ...
```

Then you need to add an onClick handler to your links, like so:

```html
<a href="#" onClick="selectTitle('Sobre')">Sobre</a>
```

Finally, you will need to define the `selectTitle` function in the **JavaScript** section, which will fill the `h1` tag you added in step 1:

```js
function selectTitle(title) {
  document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = title;
}
```

Comment: you are suggesting to change the html structure in a way that requires to add an h1 element for each single submenu item... plus the function in your example is using the string literal `'title'` instead of the passed argument (typo I guess) and by the way the whole logic discriminating between submenu and child node isn't covered at all. The data attribute expected is not even cited.. in short is very far from what was expected